# Interacting identical bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, bosons, identical-particles

Say we have two spin-1 bosons on a ring of circumference L, where they interacts according to the potential $g\delta(x_1-x_2)$ (g is a real number). What is the degeneracy of the first excited state?

We need to discuss in three cases. We can define
$$\phi_n(x) = A\exp(\frac{2\pi nx}{L})$$
When $g = 0$, the spacial wave function can be symmetric
$$
\varphi=\frac{
1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_{\pm 1}(x_1)\phi_{0}(x_2) + \phi_{\pm 1}(x_2)\phi_{0}(x_1))
$$
The allowed total spin will be 2 and 0 to maintain an overall symmetric solution. Thus, the degeneracy is $2\cdot(5+1)=12$.

Similarly, we can construct an anti-symmetric spacial wave function with 2-folds spacial degeneracy. The allowed spin will be spin 1, and the degeneracy is $2\cdot 3=6$. In total we have 18 fold degeneracy for $g = 0$.

However, what would happen when $g\neq 0$? The solution depends on the sign of $g$, but I don't know how does the interaction plays its role.

Comment: You are considering the [Lieb-Liniger model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieb%E2%80%93Liniger_model).

Answer (score 1):

The Schrödinger equation with a delta interaction potential for many particles on a circle is well known and is even called “exactly solvable”. I think it's not hard to find links online. The two-particle case is also not that difficult to solve directly. After some thought, it may seem natural to try to find a solution in the following form (Bethe anzatz, many links can also be found on the Internet):
$$
\Phi(x_1,x_2) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
A_1e^{i(k_1x_1+k_2x_2)} + A_2e^{i(k_2x_1+k_1x_2)} & \mbox{if} & x_1 < x_2\\
\pm A_1e^{i(k_1x_2+k_2x_1)} \pm A_2e^{i(k_2x_2+k_1x_1)} & \mbox{if} & x_2 < x_1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where the $"+"$ sign corresponds to a symmetric spatial wave function, and the $"-"$ sign corresponds to an antisymmetric spatial wave function. Substituting this wave function into the Schrödinger equation and boundary conditions (system on a circle) gives the rules for quantizing the momenta $k_{1,2}$, which determine the spectrum of solutions. As far as I can see, in the case of a symmetric spatial wave function these rules depend on the parameter $g$, but in the case of an antisymmetric spatial wave function they do not. The last fact is due to the property $\Phi(x_1,x_1) = 0$ of the antisymmetric function.